# attach string to json ajax result

Tags: json, ajax

I have an ajax script that returns the temperature of a probe. I would like to add deg C tot he result but do not know how to do this. Can some one help. My script is below

```js
<script>
  setInterval(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url:"data.php",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){;
       $('#niamh').html(data.Gniamh);
    }
   });
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

This return the temp as a value and places it in the Div tags but I would like deg added to  it. I have tried putting °C with in the Div tags but this gets written over.

Comment: can you please explain the nature of the result, is it a json with many numbers where you want to add C to each or is it only one number? if it is only one number you can just do this: $('#niamh').html(data.Gniamh + '°C');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either add it to the return function:

```
<script>
 setInterval(function(){
     $.ajax({
         url:"data.php",
         dataType:"json",
         success: function(data){;
            $('#niamh').html(data.Gniamh + "&deg;C");
         }
     });
 }, 1000);
```

or wrap the result div with a parent:

```
<div><div id="niamh"></div>&deg;C</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. The Script part worked Grate thanks